# Series of Questions without database with Django/Twilio

Tags: python, django, twilio

I want to create a series of questions for anyone to answer. I could create a User for everyone who texts in and have a field for "completed_questions" but I was wondering if this could be done without a database. For example:

```
def HelloQuiz(request):
    body = request.REQUEST.get('Body', None)
    if body == 'Quiz me up':
        message = "2 + 3?"
    if body == '6':
        message = "Congrats! Next question: what color is green?"
    if body == 'Green':
        message == "You beat the quiz!"
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.sms(message)
    return HttpResponse(str(resp))
```

But here, if they text green as their first response, they automatically beat the quiz. I can't really think of any way to achieve this because it requires a look into a past completed action.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks kinda impossible without a DB, you can't really check if the user solved which quiz already. Though you can create a list of callers and use a text file to store it, it seems to be a work around to me.

Comment: Yeah, it was a stretch but you're right. Without some kind of reference to the past... you don't know what a caller did, in the past.

Comment: In your opinion, would it be better to write to a text file or use sqlite3?

Comment: I was about to comment but it ended up as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sqlite3 is the way to go. It's way better than writing to a text file.

What I have in mind is you can use the standard `User` model to create user, maybe use the phone number as username, something like:

```
from_number = request.REQUEST.get('From', None)
user = User.objects.get_or_create(username=from_number, ...)
# ... your code ...
```

Then you only need to define one model for the quiz and probably a relationship model:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    response = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ... fields you need ...

    def __unicode__():
        return self.message

class QuizUser(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey('Quiz')
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
```

So whenever there is a message coming in you can use some simple queryset to lookup for the right user and quiz like:

```
from_number = request.REQUEST.get('From', None)
body = request.REQUEST.get('Body', None)
user = User.objects.get(username=from_number)
quiz = Quiz.objects.get(message=body)
user_quiz = QuizUser.objects.get(user=user, quiz=quiz)
# ... your code ...
```

This is just my basic opinion.

You can of course go for you original plan, use custom user model and add `completed_quiz` field and have the list of quiz as a static list.

Have fun coding!

Comment: Just wondering, what do you think the benefits in this case in using the Django User module vs. creating a custom class Callers(models.Model).

Comment: Somehow I don't think you can benefit anything from using User model (or anything related), you don't need username password, authentication or that stuff so I guess creating your own model is the best choice.